# On load tap changer controller switching

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

A 20/25 MVA transformer has an On load tap changer (oltc). Here a HMK7 Controller is used to control the motor drive of oltc. Which seems like
[image]

There are two buttons 1-N & N-1. Red seven segments show the tap position. To increase voltage we press N-1 button which reduces tap position by 1. There are 25 tap position. For details see this

[image]

May be the tap changer connection diagram will be helpful to understand the question.

[image]

So my question is instead of being two buttons named raise and lower why there are 1-N & N-1 buttons? What's the meaning of these two notations?

Comment: It's an English panel produced by a Chinese company.  You'll probably be better off asking questions when you find one which *doesn't* have mysterious mistranslations.  If it said N-1 and N+1, would you understand that?

Comment: I don't think so. HMK7 controls a motor drive named SHM-1. In that motor drive I also found same push buttons named N-1 & 1-N. That means rather than using HMK7 Controller you can change tap position in the field

Comment: I also read the manual. But there is no clarification about those notations.

Comment: One thing to think about : "Raise" and "Lower" are ambiguous, if the transformer can be used both to step up and step down. The highest tap position corresponds to the lowest turns ratio, there is scope for some confusion...

Comment: Just think raise tap position for "raise" not voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Transformers like that often have have taps numbered with N in the middle, and 1L, 2L, ... for lowering and 1R, 2R, ... for raising. That's luckily not the case here, because N would be even more confusing then. E.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=h2Es9vpaKhQC&pg=SA2-PA18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first look, it seems to be some kind of amusing mathfail from the manufacturer. The "1-n" appears in [their manual](http://www.hltc.fr/docs/Tap%20Changer%20Selecting%20Manual%20-HM0%20154%20000-Feb.2010.pdf) as well.
For comparison an [ABB tap-changer](https://library.e.abb.com/public/c9cefefe99072f00c125726e0055f9ba/1ZSE%205492-104%20en%20Rev%209.pdf) uses n-1 and n+1 its manual; [same thing](https://library.e.abb.com/public/52a63230a4d64211c1257c1c0031b925/1ZSC000562-ABE%20en_pdfx1a.pdf) in another ABB manual.

I've found however [the brochure](http://www.gzcz.net.cn/en/zlxz/Data_Download_en/yb/zvm.pdf) of another Chinese product, but by a different company, and this one uses arrows, not minus/dash between 1 and n:

[image]

Besides making fun of the Chinglish on the faceplate, this one is perhaps less nonsensical than "1-n". The arrows notation could be taken as some kind of increment/decrement notation like --n and n++ would be in programming. Or perhaps (more likely) the arrows indicate going from tap position 1 toward tap position N (i.e the max tap number) and vice-versa.

Comment: Now it makes a little sense. If N is the maximum tap number 1->N increase tap from 1 to N & vice versa for N->1. Though it is noted as N-1 in the controller but in the HMK7 manual it was noted as N->1.

Comment: I think the N is for the neutral position (the 0 position). So 1->N means "lower position toward neutral position" to the neutral position, and N->1 means "neutral position toward to higher position".